# clipboard.js where the desired copied text div will have same class or id as other divs on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, copy-paste, clipboard.js

I have multiple buttons that when clicked, should copy the text from a specific div. However, because the divs have IDs that are repeated on the page several times (due to being in a loop), I am unable to make sure the text that is copied is from the closest div with that ID.

I am using Clipboard.js, but it is not a requirement if I can get the same functionality with a normal function.

My HTML code looks like this so far... but remember, it's in a dynamically-generated loop. so "shortcodesTable" and each "shortcode1" div will be repeated.

```
<div id="shortcodesTable">
    <h4>Short Codes</h4>
        <div>
            <h5>Shortcode 1</h5>
            <button class="copy-btn" data-clipboard-target="#shortcode1">Copy</button>
            <div id="shortcode1"><pre><code> ... ... ... </code></pre></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h5>Shortcode 2</h5>
            <button class="copy-btn" data-clipboard-target="#shortcode2">Copy</button>
            <div id="shortcode2"><pre><code> ... ... ... </code></pre></div>
        </div>
```

and my JS is the basic function from the clipboard.js documentation:

```
var clipboard = new Clipboard('.copy-btn');

clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
        console.info('Copied Text:', e.text);

        e.clearSelection();
    });

    clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
        console.error('Action:', e.action);
        console.error('Trigger:', e.trigger);
    });
```

For more clarification, my code is looping through an api of credit cards and populating content for each one. This table that needs the copy functionality is within that loop. It looks like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    var 1 = blah;
    var 2 = blah2;

    $('<div>'+
        '<div>'+
           var 1 +
        '</div>' +
        '<div>'+
           var 2 +
        '</div>' +
        '<div id="shortcodesTable">'+
           '<h4>Short Codes</h4>'+
           '<div>'+
              '<h5>Shortcode 1</h5>'+
              '<button class="copy-btn" data-clipboard-target="#shortcode1">Copy</button>'+
              '<div id="shortcode1"><pre><code> ... ... ... </code></pre></div>'+
           '</div>'+
           '<div>'+
              '<h5>Shortcode 2</h5>'+
              '<button class="copy-btn" data-clipboard-target="#shortcode2">Copy</button>'+
              '<div id="shortcode2"><pre><code> ... ... ... </code></pre></div>'+
           '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
      '</div>').appendTo('.some-div');
}
```

Comment: You can not have more than one element with the same id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a counter variable or simply the index of your loop to give your elements unique ids.

As the W3 states:

> The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters.
>   https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Working example using template strings

```
function createShortcodeTables(iterations, root) {
  let html = ''
  for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    html += `
      <div id="shortcodesTable-${i}">
      <h4>Short Codes</h4>
      <div>
        <h5>Shortcode 1</h5>
        <button class="copy-btn" data-clipboard-target="#shortcode-${i}">Copy</button>
        <div id="shortcode-${i}"><pre><code> Text of shortcode #${i} </code></pre></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h5>Shortcode 2</h5>
        <button class="copy-btn" data-clipboard-target="#shortcode-${i}-${i}">Copy</button>
        <div id="shortcode-${i}-${i}"><pre><code> Text of shortcode #${i}-${i} </code></pre></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    `
  }
  root.innerHTML = html
}

const rootElement = document.querySelector('.root')

createShortcodeTables(10, rootElement)

const clipboard = new Clipboard('.copy-btn');

clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
  console.info('Copied Text:', e.text);

  e.clearSelection();
});

clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
  console.error('Action:', e.action);
  console.error('Trigger:', e.trigger);
});
```

[Example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rk4rmuma/)

**Edit:**

```
... +
'<button class="copy-btn" data-clipboard-target="#shortcode1">Copy</button>' +
'<div id="shortcode1"><pre><code> ... ... ... </code></pre></div>' + ...
```

in your *data-clipboard-target* and the corresponding *id* attributes you have to add your index variable *i*. To do that you have to close your string and concatenate your index variable to it, otherwise it would print you the literal character *i*.

```
... +
'<button class="copy-btn" data-clipboard-target="#shortcode-' + i + '">Copy</button>' +
'<div id="shortcode-' + i + '"><pre><code> ... ... ... </code></pre></div>' + ...
```

Note the single quotes I've added inside your HTML attributes to close the string literal.

More conceptual example:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
  console.log('<div id="some-id-' + index + '"></div>');
}
```

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jh0hL1jv/4/) with string concatenation.

Comment: so this works, but my "shortcodesTable" is just one div within a bunch of other code that is being created in a jquery function and appended to a div in the body, so i'm not sure how to loop that within that code. how should i go about getting the index of the loop to give my elements unique ids like you suggested?

Comment: In your case your index is the variable _i_ that you've declared in your for loop.
Since your are basically concatenating a string in your jQuery function you can add your index variable to it by 'closing' the string and do another concatenation.

Example:
    var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
      console.log('<div id="some-id-' + index + '"></div>');
    }

https://jsfiddle.net/jh0hL1jv/4/

Comment: i knew itd be something simple that i just wasnt thinking of. that worked. thanks!